# How to specify the highest indexed array component?

Tags: stan, rstan

Suppose that the following in stan file.

```
transformed parameters {

  real <lower=0,upper=1>p[C];

}
```

where `C` is a positive integer specified by the data block.

Then by `p[1]` we can extract the first component. `p[C]` also extract the `C`-th componet ? Or `p[C]` is indicate the set of `p[1],p[2],....p[C]` ?

For example, Which does the code `p[C] = 1` means ?

1)ONLY the C-th component of `p` is one

or

2)ALL components of p (i.e., `p[1],p[2],....p[C]` )  is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example,

```
transformed parameters {
  real<lower = 0, upper = 1> p[C]; // multivalued
  p[C] = 1; // scalar
}
```

The first `C-1` elements of `p` are undefined, which is probably not good, although it is valid syntax.

Alternatively,

```
transformed parameters {
  real<lower = 0, upper = 1> p[C] = rep_array(1, C);
}
```

defines all the elements of `p` to be 1.